# Create a folder

Tags: code-golf, file-system

### Challenge

Given an input `x`, create a directory (AKA folder) in the file system with the name `x`.

Languages that are not able to create file system directories are excluded from this challenge.

The directory may be created anywhere, as long as the location is writable to the user running the program. Assume that the program is run as a non-privileged user on a modern Linux (or Windows if needed) desktop system.

#### Clarifications

- Assume that the current directory is `$HOME`/`%USERPROFILE%`.
- Assume that no file or directory exists with the name given.
- Assume that the filename will only contain the characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`.
- Assume that the filename will always be 8 characters long or shorter.

### Rules

- The directory must actually be created. You can't just say "I made it in /dev/null".
- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: Apart from leaving *zero* room for golfing (in what languages would the straightforward approach not be the shortest?), your challenge is also unclear. Does the third paragraph mean we have to create it in our home folder? Can we assume we're already there? What if a directory or file of the same name already exists?

Comment: Also, you might consider waiting a few minutes for feedback before complaining about the lack of it.

Comment: @Dennis Clarified.

Comment: Which characters can appear in the filename?

Comment: @Dennis a-zA-Z0-9 upto 8 chars

Comment: You should really start using the Sandbox, Mendeleev.

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB/Octave, 6 bytes

```
@mkdir
```

Creates a function handle named `ans` to the built-in function `mkdir` which accepts the folder to be created as a string

```
ans('folder_to_create')
ans('/absolute/path/to/folder/to/create')
```

Comment: Where do you get input?

Comment: @Mendeleev It's passed to the function

Comment: all right, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 11 + 1 = 12 bytes

+1 for `-n`

```ruby
Dir.mkdir$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/3yWzSC83OyWzSCX@f0FpSbECSCA1r6QoM7VYQ11PXfN/Wn7@v/yCksz8vOL/unkA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 5 bytes

```julia
mkdir
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/Z@mYPs/Nzsls@i/UoWSQo2dQhpXUWpiClBAQxPETcksLshJrPwPAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Java, <strike>33</strike> 31 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Phoenix - removing curly braces around lambda.

```java
s->new java.io.File(s).mkdir();
```

In the form of a `Consumer<String>` where `s` is the name of the folder to create.

Comment: You don't need the curly brackets for a lambda like that, I think.

Comment: @Phoenix You are correct. Thanks!

Comment: Your code now has a curly brace on the end that you seen to have missed.

Comment: @Phoenix thanks again, I'm not very good at this ;P

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 8 bytes

```bash
mkdir $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Pzc7JbNIQcXwf07x//9p@fkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

```python
import os
os.mkdir
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 6 bytes

```
@md %*
```

<s>Try it online!</s>

Comment: can't you remove the `@`? other answers output to stdout as well

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 46 bytes

```go
import."os"
func f(n string){Mkdir(n,ModeDir)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 14 bytes

```
Run["md "<>#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78r/E/qDQvWik3RUHJxk45Vu2/ZrRSYlKyUux/AA)

---

The [trivial approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123911/69850) is longer. Surprise! (demonstrates that Mathematica is very verbose)

Works on Windows only, where `md` is the command to create a directory. See [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154632/69850) or [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123931/69850).

---

Explanation:

```
Run["md "<>#]&   Anonymous function.

    "md "        String literal "md ". (with a trailing space to separate
                   the command and the parameter (directory name)
           #     The input.
         <>      `StringJoin` together.
Run[        ]    Runs as a command.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
CreateDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 35 bytes

```c#
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory
```

Does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 2 bytes

```
md
```

`md` means **m**ake **d**irectory. Here it is in action:

```
C:\tmp>set f=md

C:\tmp>%f% foo

C:\tmp>dir f*.*
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 6CC3-3025

 Directory of C:\tmp

02-Feb-18  09:56    <DIR>          foo
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  378,122,883,072 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 bytes

Prefix function.

```apl
⎕MKDIR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHfVN9vV08g4A8BfW0/Hx1rkdtE4GCwR4K6jnFCro5BeoA)

Answer (score -2):

## tcl, don't know how to count

My count could be:

- 13, if everything on `file mkdir $x` is accounted.
- 12, if `file mkdir $`as how I have seen in some answers `x` is not taken into account
- 11, because in tcl whenever you use the value of `x` , you type `$x`, so only `file mkdir`  is taken into account
- 10, if is `file mkdir` by removing the trailing space from previous.

Source:

```
file mkdir $x
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRXZqNEpXWnpJUW8) — Please reserve it for question asker. Look at files tree at the left where there is only `root` and `main.tcl` . Click the `Execute` button, it will run a script command on the green area; In the top of the files tree there is a `Refresh` button symbolized by an icon, click it and see `folder1` and `folder2` appearing.